# How do I use "I had been watching" in a sentence?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, progressive-aspect

Please help me to write a sentence with

> I had been watching

What does it mean exactly?

When do we use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I had been watching the program regularly but I missed the last episode.**

We use **had** *(v)* and the **past participle** for the **past perfect**:

> *I had finished the work (This means, I had certainly finished it)*.

The **past perfect continuous** is formed with *had been* and the *gerund -ing* form of the verb:

> *I had been finishing the work (I was doing that and about to finish)*.

Also,

Use the past perfect tense for something that begun in the past until a given time in the past:

> *Before being sacked, he had been associated with the company for nearly 30 years.*

Comment: Thank you Maulik. Would you please check this: "I had been working in my fathers store until he passed away." Is it  correct?

Comment: @Gata Yes. Match it with given example. Nevertheless, it's *at my father's store.*

Comment: @GATA, in other words, in general, one can use the past perfect continuous to express what one had been doing and was still doing at the referred time, which in your sentence is fixed by 'until he passed away', even if I hope it is not true :)

Comment: Thank you Maulik and user2793 for your instructive and  useful comments.

Comment: @GATA 1, you may choose any answer and select it. This will help maintain this board

Comment: Nice post, but with one weird example (at least to me). That "had been watching" sounds fine to me, but "had been finishing" gave me some peculiar thoughts (sort of, how long had you been trying to finish it, will it ever finish anyway?). I'd probably say "I was going to finish" or "I was about to finish" instead.

Comment: @DamkerngT. True...it may look incomplete sentence but then the message is conveyed in this context. *I had been finishing the work but then... something happened.*